# HTML/CSS Hidden Table Rows (not working)

Tags: html, css, html-table, rows, hidden

I have a table with some hidden rows. However, it seems that the hidden row is generated inside the first column of the visible rows.

Let me explain...

I have a table that lists team names. When a team name is clicked, a hidden row below the team name is displayed with the team member names. When I click on the Team Name, I expect [to get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWlaJ.png), but instead [I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzeh0.png).

This is the code generating the rows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
  if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
  else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
}
</script>

  <tr>
    <td width=5% style="text-align:center; padding: 10px;">1</td>
    <td width= 10% style="text-align:center; padding: 10px;">M-2</td>
    <td width=40% style="text-align:left; padding: 10px;"  ><a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('tri-384')">Engi-Nerds</a></td>
    <td width=5% style="text-align:center;">15</td>
    <td width=5% style="text-align:center;">11</td>
    <td width=5% style="text-align:center;">11</td>
    <td width=5% style="text-align:center;">3</td>
    <td width=7% style="text-align:center;">0</td>
    <td width=8% style="text-align:center;">40</td>
    <td width=10% style="text-align:center;">08:43:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tri-384" style="display:none;">
    <td width=5%></td>
    <td width=10%></td>
    <td width=40%>--Todd Rebol<br />--Chris Beers</td>
    <td colspan=7 width=45%></td>
  </tr>
```

Interestingly, when I remove the `style="display:none;"` from the second row, the table rows display just fine (although the names row is no longer hidden).

Any idea what I am missing?

-- edit --

Thanks to Little Santi, I have this working now. It was a simple change. I had to update`display = "block"` to `display = "table-row"` in my JS code.

Comment: Could you JSFiddle this?

Comment: Let me work on that.

Comment: Here is JSFiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/mannyotr/v5sf5rgr/

Comment: It would be easier to add/remove a CSS Class to play with `display:none/table-row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it: Just change `display=block` by `display=table-row`. The displaying layout is different.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!